# Is there a way to scrape the text that is not inside its own tags with Simple HTML DOM Parser?

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

The HTML structure of what i am scraping is this:

```
<section class="arbeidsgiverinfo">
    <h1 id="arbeidsgivernavn">ENITRO AS</h1>
    <p class="details clearfix"><span class="postdel">XXXXXXXXX<br>
    4621 KRISTIANSAND S<br></span> <span class="adressedel"><span class=
    "subdel">Telefon: XXXXXXX<br></span></span> <span class=
    "kommunikasjondel"><span class="subdel"><span>E-post:</span> <a href=
    "mailto:stilling@enitro.no" target=
    "_blank"><span>XXXXXXXXX</span></a></span> <span class=
    "subdel"><span>Web:</span> <a href="http://www.enitro.no" target=
    "_blank"><span>www.enitro.no</span></a></span></span></p>

    <!-- THIS PORTION -->
    Enitro AS leverer konsulenttjenester og løsninger innenfor IT-infrastruktur.
    Enitro har spesialkompetanse spesielt innenfor nettsky, nettverk,
    sikkerhet og backup. Ble etablert i 2007 og er et velrennomert
    IT-selskap i Kristiansand. Vi leter fortiden etter nye salgs
    konsulenter som kan hjelpe oss med å øke salget og utviklingen på Xerox
    porteføljen. Vi leiter etter utadvendte mennesker med stort pågangsmot
    og ønske for å lære og utvikle seg i teknisk salg.
    <!-- /THIS PORTION -->

</section>
```

Is this possible? I havent found a way to do it yet and i have searched a lot on the subject.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the PHP syntax but the text should be a text node that is the nextSibling of the `p` tag.  If Simple HTML DOM supports nextSibling you could try that.